# Get data from a Google Sheet within a Google Home Action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

Developing a small action for my Google Home with Api.ai.

I would like to pull specific data from a Google sheet or some sort of spreadsheet database (Google Sheets seemed like the easiest since it is Google made.) For read back within my Home action.

Is this possible yet? If so how do I go about linking the two?

Comment: This should be possible. Is the information you want to store/access private to the user, or public (e.g. public transportation times)? If private, is it valuable enough that you'd like to persist it with an account system, or not valuable enough so that something like a cookie would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a custom [webhook](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/webhook-format) (see also the [api.ai documentation](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook)) you can interact with Google sheets too. You just need to think about how you get access to those documents.

Comment: Regarding accessing google sheets, look into Google App Scripts. They allow you to do those kinds of things